# Neo4j REST Cypher Column Alias Issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to make a simple CYPHER query using the Neo4J REST API. Here is the query:

```
START n=node(*)
RETURN n as Node1, sum(n.TestInt?)
```

I get the following error:

> unknown identifier 'n'

I also tried the following:

```
START n=node(*)
RETURN n as Node1, sum(Node1.TestInt?)
```

but I still an same error:

> unknown identifier 'Node1'

The same query without any alias doesn't return any error and works flawlessly.

Am I wrong to think that the alias should have no impact on this? Why is the identifier of the node suddenly not recognized?

I am in a situation where I need to work with alias. Is this a bug fixable only in Neo4j?

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug that was in Neo4j 1.8 when you aliased a value you couldn't access it under the aliased name.

Can you try in your case:

```
START n=node(*) RETURN n as Node1, sum(n.TestInt?)
```

Also what you want to do is probably group by something and then sum over those values, right now you're returning exactly `n.TestInt` for each row, no sum.